# automatically download a report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

This is the code that i have made but now working to save the report to the directory:

As you see i follow pretty much a lot of microsoft tutorials of how use this class of reporting service, but still dont get how get it working

```
 'objetos de reporting
        Dim rs As New reportingservice.ReportingService2010
        Dim rsExec As New ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService

        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

        'datos generales
        Dim historyID As String = Nothing
        Dim deviceInfo As String = Nothing
        Dim format As String = "PDF"
        Dim results As Byte()
        Dim encoding As String = String.Empty
        Dim mimeType As String = String.Empty
        Dim extension As String = String.Empty
        Dim warnings As ReportExecution.Warning() = Nothing
        Dim streamIDs As String() = Nothing
        Dim filename As String = "C:/Users/gdedieu/Desktop/reporte.pdf"        ' Change to where you want to save
        Dim _reportName As String = "per_anexo_1"
        Dim _historyID As String = Nothing
        Dim _forRendering As Boolean = False
        Dim _values As ReportExecution.ParameterValue() = Nothing
        Dim _credentials As reportingservice.DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
        Dim ei As ReportExecution.ExecutionInfo = rsExec.LoadReport(_reportName, historyID)

        'definimos el parámetro
        _values(0).Name = "an1_id"
        _values(0).Value = 1

        rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(_values, "en-us")
        results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo, extension, mimeType, encoding, warnings, streamIDs)

        Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

        stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length)
        stream.Close()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: isn't this the exact same problem you had before?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a subscription via the Report Manager and specifying the Report Delivery Options value for 'Delivered By:' as 'Report Server File Share'.

This lets you specify a path for a report file to be written to - you will need to ensure that the Reporting Services server has write access to the destination.